# Is there a way to install Windows 8 as a dual-boot starting with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, boot-partition

Is a way to dual-boot With Ubuntu and windows 8 with going from Ubuntu? I'm kind of stumped, I tried to do it earlier and it overwrote the grub so, I had to go in a live disc and fix the grub from there and I finally got it working again.

Comment: It's the correct way. Windows will always overwrite mbr, you need to reinstall grub. Best tool to do this is `boot-repair`

Answer (score 1):

Thats the only solution i know (or at least the easiest one)... free up some space and install windows, but as you mentioned, you will need to restore grub. You can do this from a live CD.

Restoring grub has become a very simple task, check out the graphical way in the following link
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows